# query is not a function error using firebase function to call firebase firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i am trying to pull a collection from firestore using firebase functions gen2. my code looks like below

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const { getDocs} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();

const cors = require('cors')({origin:true});

export const getReviews = onRequest(async(request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, async() => {
        logger.info("getReviews logging!", {structuredData: true});
   
        const reviews:any = []
        const appRef = db.collection("feedback");
        const appQuery = db.query(appRef);
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(appQuery);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc:any) => {
            let data:any 
            data = doc.data()
            reviews.push(data)
        });

        response.send(reviews);
      });
  
 });
```

on running this fails with error query is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the Node SDKs for Firebase still use the namespaced API syntax. For the `firebase-admin` SDK, this is provided by the [`@google-cloud/firestore` Client SDK](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/). [`query()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#query) was introduced with the Firebase Cloud Firestore Modular SDK and is not available in the Node SDKs.

To correct your code, you would replace these lines:

```js
const appRef = db.collection("feedback");
const appQuery = db.query(appRef);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(appQuery);
```

with

```js
const appColRef = db.collection("feedback"); // best practice to use "ColRef" instead of just "Ref"
const querySnapshot = await appColRef.get()
```

To a certain extent, you can refer to the [Modular SDK Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) and use it to downgrade your familiarity with the client side code.

**Note:** `firebase-functions/v2/firestore` is used to define 2nd Gen [Firestore Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) and is not used to access your Firestore database. That is the responsibility of `firebase-admin/firestore`.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Where do i add the where clause? i tried to append it to your code from the another response below but that throws error "where is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

To query a collection in firebase function v2 you should use
`await db.collection("feedback").where("user", "==", "bob").get()`